# comparison of selected option with correct answer in a group of radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

How do I fetch the selected option from a group of radio buttons.What are the possible ways to check the selected option with the correct answer?
(am a beginner)This is the code which am working on.Just included 2 questions with 4 radio buttons each and they were grouped.Now I have to display a score after checking for the correct answer

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyRadioButton {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioRadio");
    private JLabel timerl = new JLabel("Press Button to start");
    private JPanel butp = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
    private JLabel q1=new JLabel("Qn 1:Who is the first President Of India?");
    private JLabel q2=new JLabel("Qn 2:Who is the first Prime Minister Of India?");

    private JPanel panel2=new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel3=new JPanel();
    private JLabel label=new JLabel();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Start Exam");
    private JRadioButton rd1=new JRadioButton("a)Nehru");
    private JRadioButton rd2=new JRadioButton("b)R.Prasad");
    private JRadioButton rd3=new JRadioButton("c)S.R.Krishnan");
    private JRadioButton rd4=new JRadioButton("d)GV.Mavlankar"); 
    private JRadioButton rd5=new JRadioButton("a)Nehru");
    private JRadioButton rd6=new JRadioButton("b)R.Prasad");
    private JRadioButton rd7=new JRadioButton("c)S.R.Krishnan");
    private JRadioButton rd8=new JRadioButton("d)GV.Mavlankar"); 

    ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

    public int result=0;
    private Timer mytimer;
    private String ss = "Time Remaining %02d Seconds!";
    private int elapsedSeconds = 0;
    private int total = 60;
    JLayeredPane pane=new JLayeredPane();


    public MyRadioButton() {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                if (mytimer != null && mytimer.isRunning()) {
                    //String t = String.format("Result:Your Score is %d", result);
                   //label.setText(t); 
                    mytimer.stop();
                    elapsedSeconds = 0;
                    timerl.setText("Exam Terminated");
                } else {
                    panel1.setBounds(0, 100, 500, 100);
                    panel1.add(q1);
                    pane.add(panel1,pane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                    panel2.setBounds(0,200,500,100);
                    panel2.add(q2);
                    pane.add(panel2,pane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                    panel3.setBounds(0, 300, 500, 100);
                    pane.add(panel3,pane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                    panel3.add(label);


                   panel1.add(rd1);
                   panel1.add(rd2);
                   panel1.add(rd3);
                   panel1.add(rd4);
                   panel2.add(rd5);
                   panel2.add(rd6);
                   panel2.add(rd7);
                   panel2.add(rd8);
                   group1.add(rd1);
                   group1.add(rd2);
                   group1.add(rd3);
                   group1.add(rd4);
                   group2.add(rd5);
                   group2.add(rd6);
                   group2.add(rd7);
                   group2.add(rd8);
                    mytimer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
                    mytimer.start();
                    String t = String.format(ss, total);
                    timerl.setText(t);

                }
            }
        });

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.add(pane);
        butp.setBounds(0,0,500,100);
        butp.add(button);
        butp.add(timerl);
        pane.add(butp,pane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            elapsedSeconds++;
            if (elapsedSeconds == total) {
                mytimer.stop();
                elapsedSeconds = 0;
                timerl.setText("Time Up");
            } else {
                String t = String.format(ss, total - elapsedSeconds);
                timerl.setText(t);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyRadioButton r = new MyRadioButton();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with the example discussed in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton), and ask a _specific question_.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever. That's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `ActionListener` to each button in which you can set, for example, class field to currently selected radio button value.

```
...
String firstAnswer;
String secondAnswer;
...

private FirstQuestionActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     firstAnswer = e.getActionCommand();
  }
}

private SecondQuestionActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     secondAnswer = e.getActionCommand();
  }
}
```

And use it this way: `rb1.addActionListener(new FirstQuestionActionListener());`